# PXFilteredProcessingJoin to PXResultSet

Tags: acumatica

Is it applicable to cast `PXFilteredProcessingJoin` to `PXResultSet`?
It will help me to optimize my code

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't actually cast `PXFilteredProcessingJoin` (or even mere `PXProcessing`) to `PXResultSet` - these are vastly different types, which pursue different goals.

At the same time they are closely related because calling `Select(..)` on the `PXFilteredProcessingJoin` class (or anything that is `PXSelectBase`-like) actually yields an instance of `PXResultset`, so the following is valid code:

```
PXResultset<ARInvoice> items = Documents.Select(this);
```

where `Documents` is defined in the same graph as

```
public PXFilteredProcessingJoin<ARInvoice,
    Where<ARInvoice.released, Equal<boolFalse>>> Documents;
```